# How to make Wordpress thumbnails grid same size

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4, thumbnails

I am trying to generate Wordpress thumbnails and title from posts into grid. It is generating  as expected, however can not make thumbnails size the same. If image height is bigger than width, it is not cropping as I expect from my custom `add_image_size()` function.

Any ideas how to make images in grid same size?

[image: Current view after generating grid]

Code that I am using in Wordpress functions:

```
add_image_size( 'cust-thumb', 400, 300, true );
```

Custom theme file code:

```
<div class="container-fluid p-5">
    <div class="row">
    <?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-12 text-center pb-4 col">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('cust-thumb'); ?>
        <h5 class="pt-2"><?php the_title(); ?></h5></a>
    </div> 
    <?php endwhile; ?> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
add_image_size( 'cust-thumb', 400, 300, array( 'center', 'center' ) );
```

Comment: Thank you, however, thumbnails looks same, nothing changed.

Comment: regenerate thumbnails

Comment: Looks like I was missing it all the time, thank you, it worked!